# Unable to setup GAE SSL for a custom domain

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm unable to complete the ssl setup for my custom domain as per the instructions here:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl

After entering my GAE Application Id into the "App Engine Application ID:" field within google apps I am taken to my list of apps in GAE. The docs state that I will "... be redirected to the Admin Console of the application named in the previous step." and that there will be a button to push to accept the ssl-related charges. Not happening.

The Google Apps for Business support people have not been able to help (they draw the line at GAE) and I've not been able to find any other similar cases. So I'm stuck.

I have set up billing both within my GAE and Apps account.

Let me know if there's a better place to get help for this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was entering the Project Number, not the app id.

Comment: I suggest to edit the answer to make it less colloquial and flag it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to be aware of is that currently you need to include the "s~" prefix when specifying hte App Id.  Also, your App needs to have billing enabled.